# Adding text "no records found" in datagrid

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

Hi i want one message if `DataGrid` is null, but at the moment nothing, here is my code:

```
Private Sub fill_tbldespesas()
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim BD_SimuladorNT As New Negocio.Simulador.SimulacoesNT
        ds = BD_SimuladorNT.Fill_DGDespesas(CurrentContext.CurrentUserId, CurrentContext.CurrentCulture.idCulture)
        Dim dv As DataView
    If (Not (dv Is Nothing)) Then
        If ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            dv = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
            dv.RowFilter = "IncluidaProp = 'T'"
            dgdespesas.DataSource = dv
            dgdespesas.DataBind()
        End If

        If ds.Tables.Count < 1 Then
            Dim lblempty As Label = DirectCast(FindControl("lblgridEmpty"), Label)
            dgdespesas.DataSource = Nothing
            Me.dgdespesas.ShowHeader = False
            'gridEmpty.text = "Company Name must not be empty"
            'dgdespesas.rows.clear()
            lblempty.Text = "no results"

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @equisde : when editing please add proper comments, not a single word

Comment: @dreamweiver I dunno; I think the edit comment got the point across OK. But a better explanation never hurts. Often a good idea for suggested edits, too.